# How to get the current rowindex of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want the current row in a `DataGridView`. Not by mouse click but by pressing enter...

I know of this:

```
datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

and

```
datagridview.CurrentRow.Index
```

and

```
datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Index
```

...

My problem is that generally this works ok except when I get to the last row. Because it always gets the index of the second last row.

Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Can you put some code of your project/method/event which returns you this bad index?

Comment: @MaciejŚwierczek thats the thing it is no event really.. When I press enter I want to show the currently selected row. So since I can´t get it by any event parameter I have to look which datagridview is selected as I posted.

Comment: You DON'T use event (for example KeyDown) or you CAN'T use event?

Comment: @MaciejŚwierczek yes I mean I use an event. Meaning I have a win forms and a datagrid view and then I have an event key down which triggers the whole thing but there is not information in the event parameters about the row selected or anything.

Comment: I think you are beginner so let me explain you - YOU GOT LOT OF INFORMATIONS IN EVENTS PARAMETERS!!! Please look at "sender" object in debug mode just after event is fired.

Comment: What does it mean: *Because it always gets the index of the second last row.*?!

Comment: please provide the code that gives you always the wrong row

Comment: Providing your code of the KeyDown event or whatever event you are using to capture the Enter key would be helpful.  Also - does your grid expose the new row so users can add a new row?

Comment: Do you perhaps have AllowUserToAddRows = true and keep adding rows..?

Comment: @TaW AllowUserToAddRows is false!

Comment: @MaciejŚwierczek why would the selected row of a child datagridview be in the KeyPress event sender of a form? Lookin at the sender object is the first thing I did!

Comment: @RezaAghaei I get the same index for the last and the second last row!

Comment: @RomCoo I did just look above. There isn´t more to it and everybody knows how a event looks like

Comment: @joohaha Could you post a really simple code to show me what you mean by *I get the same index for the last and the second last row!* :)

Comment: You do realize that pressing enter by default moves to the next row, right?

Comment: @TaW that actually is a good point exept that the index is right for all the other rows. Why would this just be an error with the last row?

Comment: Well in the last row and with AllowUserToAddRows = lase it can't move on. so that certainly will cause different behaviour. But not seeing your code I can't tell for sure what would be the best way..

Comment: @TaW I really don´t know what code to provide since there isn´t anything exept what I showed.

Comment: Well, the event you use, of course. Is it KeyPress, or KeyDown or what? Here is how I would handle it: `private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == 13)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.CurrentRow + "");
        }            
    `

Comment: @TaW sorry! The last comment you wrote actually did the trick! Thanks! If you put as an answer I´ll submit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catching the current row in a `DataGridView` is really quite simple and you have posted two ways which work just fine:

```
int currentRow = datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

or:

```
int currentRow = datagridview.CurrentRow.Index
```

The **third** one is actually rather problematatic as, depending on the `SelectionMode` of the `DataGridView` the current row may **not** be selected.

But **your problems** come from trying to grab the index in response to the user hitting the **Enter-key**.

This by default will **move** the current cell one row down, **if** there is one. So the behaviour will vary between the last and the other rows..

If there isn't a 'next' row, the current cell will either stay where it is or, if `AllowUserToAddRows` is true, the DGV will create a new, empty row and move there.

So if you always want to get the current index without moving the current cell you need to prevent the processing of the Enter-key.

Here is one way to do that:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // don't pass the enter key on to the DGV:
        e.Handled = true;
        // now store or proecess the index:
        Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.CurrentRow + "");
    }            
}
```

The user will still be able to move around with the cursor keys.

Answer (score 0):

If DataGridView is configured to allow row adds, current cell selection is a little confusing.

Let's say there is a DataGridView control with 5 valid rows of data, and user clicks on row 5. Then user clicks on row 6 and the new row is added to the display and the cell on row 6 is highlighted.

But `CurrentCell.RowIndex` and `CurrentRow.Index` remain set to row 5 (actual value=4), even though the UI no longer shows the focus there.

This has nothing to do with mouse or keyboard.

I detect this case with code like this:

```
bool lastRowSelected = false;

if (grid.SelectedCells != null)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (cell.RowIndex >= grid.NewRowIndex)
        {
            lastRowSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```